# :last-child does not select the last element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to remove the background from the last `figure` element:

```
@media (min-width: 50em) {
  #mission #press figure {
    padding-left: 0;
    background: url('/assets/img/splash-green.png?1345829368') no-repeat 50% bottom;
  }
  #mission #press figure:last-child {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

The background still shows up. Am I mis-targeting?

Comment: Please show us the resulting compiled CSS or even a demo.

Comment: @Abody97 I have updated the question with the compiled CSS. Thanks.

Comment: It looks fine to me -- do you have some other CSS that defines background images? A demo would be great.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you might actually be looking for the functionality of `last-of-type` instead of `last-child`.

[LINK](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3alast-of-type)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that link, if you have a moment could you take a look at my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905061/last-child-and-last-of-type-not-working-in-sass Not sure where I'm going wrong with converting that CSS into SASS compliant code