# last-child and last-of-type not working in SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

**How would you write this to be SASS compliant?**

```
.fader { display: inline-block; }
.fader img:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}​
```

Basically I'm just replicating this example of fading in one image over another [**(found here.)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039174/jquery-hover-image-change-animation)

His JFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Be/3/

However his example is straight CSS, I'm working on a project in SASS and am not sure about how to correctly translate it.

### My Code

Note in my example below, the img hover isn't working correctly (both images are showing up and no rollover fadein action happens)

**My CodePen:**
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/xnjso

I tried

```
.try-me img:last-child & .tryme img:last-of-type
```

But the : throws SASS compile errors, the code below works

```
.try-me img last-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

However it spits out CSS which doesn't help me:

```
.container .home-content .try-me img last-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

---

### UPDATE: Working Codepen:

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/xnjso

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nesting is not a requirement with Sass.  Don't feel obligated to do so if there's no need to break up the selectors.

```css
.try-me img:last-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

If you are applying styles to the image and then specific styles to the last-of-type, then this what it would look like when you nest it:

```css
.try-me img {
    // styles

    &:last-of-type {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked :D yeah that was my problem, trying to nest everything, should have stepped back and realized that I was trying to nest 2 different selectors. Working Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/xnjso

Answer (score 8):

Neither of the above worked for me, so.

`last-of-type` only plays nice with elements, you can select things with classes all you like but this gets handled by the elements. So say you have the following tree:

```
<div class="top-level">
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="somethingelse"></div>
</div>
```

To get to the last div with the class of `middle`, doesn't work using `last-of-type`.

My workaround was to simply change the type of element that `somethingelse` was

Hope it helps someone out, took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Hey why don't you use only CSS? You could remove all the JS, I mean hover is support right back to ie6. I guessed that you know there is no hover event just active on tablets..

I mean you will need to set an area for the image.. But I find it use full, especially if you want an href.

http://codepen.io/Ne-Ne/pen/xlbck

Just my thoughts..